# exec ffmpeg locked server

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I start encoding from php with ffmpeg exec. then for this user who initiate encoding all other php responses seems like a frozen. for this user site becomes fully unresponsable. other users, site just work fine.

why this is happening.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because you've called `session_start()` before invoking the ffmpeg process. Only one PHP process can have the a session's file open at a time, and all other requests using that session will block until either the first request completes, or `session_write_close()` is called.